# Why does my program not allow me to assign a value to one of the elements of my array?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, element

I am trying to assign a variable "gradesInSection", a double, to my array also a double. It does not allow me to do this and throws a point exception.

void findGrades()
    {//Begin findGrades

```
    Scanner grades = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nHow many grades do you have?");
    numOfGrades = grades.nextInt();  

    while (numOfGrades > 0)
    {
        numOfGrades = numOfGrades - 1;
        elementForGrade = elementForGrade + 1;

        System.out.println("\nGrade " + elementForGrade + ":");
        Scanner whatGrade = new Scanner(System.in);
        gradesInSection = whatGrade.nextDouble();

        gradeArray[elementForGrade] = gradesInSection;
    }

    for (int i = 0; gradeArray.length > i; i++)
    {
        finalGradeOfSection = gradeArray[i] + finalGradeOfSection;
    }

    finalGradeOfSection = finalGradeOfSection/numOfGrades;

    System.out.println(finalGradeOfSection);

}//End find Grades
```

Comment: which line throws the exceptoin?

Comment: what's the xeception?

Comment: gradeArray[elementForGrade] = gradesInSection;

Comment: where is gradeArray allocated? I'm guessing it's not large enough. Probably an our of bound exceptoin, or a null pointer exceptoin

Comment: it is in another class. and yes a null pinter exception

Comment: we need to know how gradeArray and elementForGrade are initialized to answer.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "point exception".  You need to [edit] your post and include the complete stack trace, and identify the line in your code that throws the exceptoin.  Otherwise your question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check that elementForGrade is not >= than gradeArray.length. My guess is that it's an out of bounds exception.

If it's a null pointer, then the code needs to have

```
double[] gradeArray = new double[20];
```

or

```
gradeArray = new double[20];
```

somewhere in the code (where 20 is the appropriate size of the array). If this line doesn't exist, then memory is never allocated leaving gradeArray as null